# Downloading with slideshare api gives "Request specific response headers cannot be used for anonymous GET requests."

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

i'm trying to download my own presentations from slideshare using it's api (i'm using the api explorer).

I get a download url as this http://s3.amazonaws.com/ppt-download/teste1mci1213resolucao-140527174635-phpapp01.pdf?response-content-disposition=attachment&Signature=SQLck4kH5onTPRQJ91ZqX%2B3BuG8%3D&Expires=1401917890&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAI6DXMWX6TBWAHQCQ

It's the same as downloading from the website, however when i enter that url in safari i get "Request specific response headers cannot be used for anonymous GET requests."

How can i solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try another browser? Seriously, that sounds like browser brokenness, because that URL is seems valid (however, now, it's expired, so I can't really say...) but, the response you are getting is exactly what you SHOULD get IF you removed everything starting with &Signature=... it's also possible that S3 is blocking the request for a different reason, such as a requirement of a specific `Referer:` header, leaving you with an ambiguous error.

Comment: Sorry for late response. I already tried different browsers but they all give the same result. What's that with the Referer: header?